# Dynamically allocated struct in function

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a school project related to bmp and im a bit stuck with the dynamic allocation aspect of things(as I have been asked to use that).
What im trying to do is pass my array using a pointer, so that the array changes its value even after the function ends,which is why i used **. However, the code just ends up crashing because of this single bit(as without it it runs smoothly).Im sure it's my use of * and & incorrectly but I don't know where and how to fix it.

```
typedef struct pixel{unsigned int r,g,b;}pixel;
void liniarizare(char *filename,pixel **liniar)
{int i;
 ... (i calculate size which is surely correct and declare fin;size=width*height*sizeof(pixel)
*liniar=(pixel*)malloc(size);
for (i=0;i<width*height;i++)
    {fread(&liniar[i]->b,1,1,fin);
     fread(&liniar[i]->g,1,1,fin);
     fread(&liniar[i]->r,1,1,fin);
     } 
 }
...
int main()
{...
 pixel *liniar
 liniarizare(filename,&liniar);
 ....}
```

Comment: Is `size` the number of bytes or the number of elements in the array?

Comment: To simplify things [it may make it more clear], change your function to: `pixel * liniarizare(char *filename)`. At the bottom, do `return liniar;` And, in `main`, do: `liniar = liniarizare(filename);`

Comment: Looks like you allocate an array of pointers with malloc, but never initialize them to point at anything, so when you try to fread through them, it crashes.  But you don't include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so its impossible to tell.

Comment: The combination of `malloc(size)` and `for (i=0;i<size;i++)` cannot be correct. You are accessing way past the bounds of allocated memory in the loop

Comment: @Dipstick It's the number of bytes (i calculate it with size=width * height * sizeof(pixel), as im planning to add width * height pixels in the array)

Comment: Following my previous comment, you probably want: `pixel *liniar = malloc(size * sizeof(pixel))` _if_ `size` is a _count_ of the number of pixels you need. The _size_ would be calculated something like: `size = sizeof(pixel) * count;`. Either way is okay, just know which it is that you are doing.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes sorry,I messed up on the site while trying to simplify the code.I corrected it now on the site but issue is still there

Comment: @CraigEstey I just checked and i actually think its the fread thats causing the problem, if i comment the loop bit it works out fine without crashing.Your version of the dynamic allocation seems to work but it still crashes when i add the reading in.(Also im not allowed to return the array in main, i just need my array to memorise the values)

Comment: I believe you _need_ the single star pointer (i.e. my version). But, the `fread` is incorrect. You're trying to read a _byte_ into an `int`, so the value will be wrong/garbage. Do: `unsigned char mybyte;` then do (for each color): `fread(&mybyte,1,1,fin); liniar[i]->r = mybyte;`

Comment: @CraigEstey Did as instructed, even removed height and width so I'm sure they're not affecting the program.  `*liniar=malloc(800*sizeof(pixel));
     for (i=0;i<800;i++)
        {   unsigned char mybyte;
            fread(&mybyte,1,1,fin); liniar[i]->r =mybyte;
            fread(&mybyte,1,1,fin); liniar[i]->g=mybyte;
            fread(&mybyte,1,1,fin); liniar[i]->b=mybyte;
         } `But unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer below. The `linear[i]->b` may be the issue [my bad]. I changed that below.

Comment: As a side issue, it's almost always better for functions like `liniarizare` to take a `FILE*` as a parameter, rather than a filename. "A function should just do one thing." Opening a file and reporting an error if the file doesn't exist is not the one thing that `liniarizare` should do. And not forcing the file to be named and opened gives more flexibility; it could be used to read images from standard input or from multi-image archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is prefaced by my top comments.

That is, have the function return `pixel *`. And, use an extra `unsigned char` variable to prevent reading a byte into an `unsigned int`

Here's a simplified version that I think should work:

```
typedef struct pixel {
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;
} pixel;

pixel *
liniarizare(char *filename)
{
    int i;

    int count = width * height;
    int size = sizeof(pixel) * count;
    pixel *liniar = malloc(size);

    pixel *pix = liniar;
    unsigned char byte;
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i, ++pix) {
        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->b = byte;

        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->g = byte;

        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->r = byte;
    }

    return liniar;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pixel *liniar;

    liniar = liniarizare(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Miraculously enough it works. The only problem is that i need to be able to pass the array by "reference" in the function and have the function provide back the modified array,which is why i insisted on using `**` and a `void`. Do you have any idea what could be wrong in my code with your advice? You said something about `linear[i]->b` being wrong.

Okay, the simplest/best way to deal with a "return" double star argument (e.g.) `whatever **retptr`) is to *ignore* this as much as possible.

That is, the function deals with the simpler `whatever *ptr` internally. This is *faster* because there is only a single dereference level and *not* a *double* dereference on *each* statement.

The return value (i.e. the double star pointer) is only set at the end *once*.

Here's my example reworked to use your original function prototype [but with my other cleanup]. Note that only two lines are changed (the function prototype and the last line of the function):

```
typedef struct pixel {
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;
} pixel;

void
liniarizare(char *filename,pixel **retval)
{
    int i;

    int count = width * height;
    int size = sizeof(pixel) * count;
    pixel *liniar = malloc(size);

    pixel *pix = liniar;
    unsigned char byte;
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i, ++pix) {
        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->b = byte;

        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->g = byte;

        fread(&byte,1,1,fin);
        pix->r = byte;
    }

    *retval = liniar;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pixel *liniar;

    liniarizare(filename,&liniar);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Sometimes the "return value" pointer needs to be read at the top of a function and set at the bottom.

Here's a "push to tail" function for a singly linked list:

```
void
push(node **list,node *new)
{
    node *head;
    node *prev;
    node *cur;

    head = *list;

    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = new;
    else
        head = new;

    new->next = NULL;

    *list = head;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Okay, now that we've got something *working*, it's time to *optimize* it [after a suitable rest period :-)].

Keep the now working version around as a reference/cross-check.

`fread` calls on single bytes are somewhat expensive.

Since your code is doing byte at a time I/O, we can replace the `fread` calls with `fgetc`. This should be slightly faster:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i, ++pix) {
    pix->b = fgetc(fin) & 0xFF;
    pix->g = fgetc(fin) & 0xFF;
    pix->r = fgetc(fin) & 0xFF;
}
```

However, we'd like to read as much as we can in single chunk. To read the *entire* image in one `fread` call would require a temp array of (e.g.) `unsigned char image[count];`. This is probably *too* much memory, and reading a large image might run into cache hit/miss issues.

But we *could* do a *row* at a time (e.g. `unsigned char row[width * 3];`). This is more tractable and probably produces as good or better results, so it may be a good compromise.

This *may* or may *not* be faster. That's why we keep the other versions around and benchmark to determine the fastest/best.

Note that this code assumes that pixels in the X dimension are physically adjacent [a reasonable possibility], but still works even if the matrix is transposed. In the end, it still reads `count` pixels in linear order, per your original code:

```
typedef struct pixel {
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;
} pixel;

void
liniarizare_by_row(char *filename,pixel **retval)
{
    int i;
    int yidx;

    int count = width * height;
    int size = sizeof(pixel) * count;
    int w3 = width * 3;
    pixel *liniar = malloc(size);

    pixel *pix = liniar;
    unsigned char row[w3];
    for (yidx = 0;  yidx < height;  ++yidx) {
        fread(row,sizeof(row),1,fin);
        for (i = 0;  i < w3;  i += 3, ++pix) {
            pix->b = row[i + 0];
            pix->g = row[i + 1];
            pix->r = row[i + 2]
        }
    }

    *retval = liniar;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pixel *liniar;
    pixel *liniar_fast;

    liniarizare(filename,&liniar);
    liniarizare_fast(filename,&liniar_fast);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Miraculously enough it works. The only problem is that i need to be able to pass the array by "reference" in the function and have the function provide back the modified array,which is why i insisted on using ** and a void. Do you have any idea what could be wrong in my code with your advice?You said something about  linear[i]->b being wrong.

Comment: It works!! Honestly thanks a lot this answer saved me from spending even more hours trying to figure out why it would crash.